# Postman returns an invalid hostname

Tags: soap, postman

I have a web service running on an AWS instance.  It can be reached here http://mqlistener-dev.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/WebService.asmx.  When I enter this url into a browser, I am taken to the instance and a page is displayed.  This is what I expected to happen.  I have code in a c# application which creates a SOAP request and I am able to send that request in and get back a response.

I now want to be able to create the SOAP request from within Postman.  I believe I have everything set up, but I keep getting a invalid hostname HTTP error 400 message.  This is the CURL code from Postman:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://mqlistener-dev.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/WebService.asmx' \
--header 'SOAPAction: http://jrstestsite.org/mq' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/xml;charset="utf-8"' \
--header 'Accept: text/xml' \
--data-raw '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-   instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <mq xmlns="http://jrstestsite.org/">
            <mqRequest> </mqRequest>
        </mq>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>'
```

Any idea why Postman is not able to reach http://mqlistener-dev.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/WebService.asmx?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Entered via Postman app (installed on Win10) manually and imported the curl request, both returned back with status 200 OK - see console output below

Imported curl request y doing the following:

1. Open POSTMAN.
2. Click on "import" tab on the upper left side.
3. Select the Raw Text option and paste your cURL command.
4. Click import button and request will be built in Postman tab
5. Click Send to post the request.

[image]

[image]

```
POST http://mqlistener-dev.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/WebService.asmx: {
  "Network": {
    "addresses": {
      "local": {
        "address": "192.168.1.206",
        "family": "IPv4",
        "port": 52349
      },
      "remote": {
        "address": "3.133.251.28",
        "family": "IPv4",
        "port": 80
      }
    }
  },
  "Request Headers": {
    "soapaction": "http://jrstestsite.org/mq",
    "content-type": "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
    "accept": "text/xml",
    "user-agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.28.4",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "32bc8802-5fcb-430e-9cd4-73cbdd0809a0",
    "host": "mqlistener-dev.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "content-length": "364"
  },
  "Request Body": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-   instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">\r\n    <soap:Body>\r\n        <mq xmlns=\"http://jrstestsite.org/\">\r\n            <mqRequest> </mqRequest>\r\n        </mq>\r\n    </soap:Body>\r\n</soap:Envelope>",
  "Response Headers": {
    "cache-control": "private, max-age=0",
    "content-type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    "server": "Microsoft-IIS/10.0",
    "x-aspnet-version": "4.0.30319",
    "x-powered-by": "ASP.NET",
    "date": "Sun, 23 Jan 2022 19:47:22 GMT",
    "content-length": "505"
  },
  "Response Body": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><soap:Body><mqResponse xmlns=\"http://jrstestsite.org/\"><mqResult><mqReturnCode>0</mqReturnCode><mqReturnMessage>999EC60001MISSING RESPONSE GENERATED DB0E01-INVALID STORAGE ADDRESS SUPPLIED TO FREE STORAGE REQUEST 'F'            </mqReturnMessage></mqResult></mqResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"
}
```

Comment: Well aint that just great.  I followed your steps on a windows machine and got back a valid response.  I wonder if it has anything to do with running on a mac.  I'll try importing the CURL into postman on my mac and see if that works.   Thanks!

Comment: works on the mac as well.  very strange.  it works when I import the CURL generated by the entry that did not work.  so odd.

Comment: Maybe there was an intermittent transport issue on the mac at the time. Anyway, it all works !!